# Moving products to another store view

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, store-view

Is there a way of moving my products to another store view? I tried to change the store view of a product and saving it but it did not work. Can anybody help?

Comment: refresh your cache and index

Answer (score 0):

In the Default View, make sure the correct websites are selected in the product configuration.

Then switch to that store view for the product, and make sure it's visibility is NOT 'not visible individually'.   Then simply reindex and refresh cache.

Comment: you mean to go to catalog/manage products/ and changing the store view from up left?

Comment: please see updated answer, sorry about that.

Comment: I can't select any store view under websites.. why so?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more info. Is your multistore setup correctly? Can you view the site on the frontend?  Screenshots of the issues you are facing.

Comment: Ok. I am dealing with the following problem. I have some configurable products in my 1st store view and i want to translate those products in order to appear with the right translation in my 2nd store view. But the configurable products appear in every store view even if i checked store view when i was creating them.